# updating variable inside label without refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Simply, I want to display the number of unread messages in a label inside the menu as follows:

```
 <li><a id="2" style="background-image:url('menu icons/comments.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: left; background-position-x: 5px;"
                       href= "viewMessages.php">Messages<label id="num_msg">(<?php echo $count; ?>)</a></li>
```

where i get `$count` as:

```
$num_messages = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(m.message_id) as cnt FROM messages m INNER JOIN member_message_member mmm ON (m.message_id = mmm.message_id)
                    WHERE mmm.member_id2 = $id AND m.seen = 0") or die(mysql_error());
                    $Mcount = mysql_fetch_assoc($num_messages);
                    $count = $Mcount['cnt'];
```

and then when a user clicks on a message:

```
 $("#sub a").click(function(){
                    mesg_id = $(this).attr('msg_id');
                    page = $(this).attr('href')
                    id = $(this).attr('mID');
                    $.ajax ({
                            data: {message_id:mesg_id},
                            type: 'POST',
                            url:  'Seen_messages.php',
                            success: function(response) {
                                if (response == 1) {

                                } else {
                                    alert(response);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                });
```

Seen_messages.php:

```
@mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("mydb") or die(mysql_error());
    $message_id = $_POST['message_id'];
   mysql_query("UPDATE `messages` SET `messages`.`seen` = TRUE WHERE message_id={$message_id}") or die (mysql_error());
   echo "1";
```

**everything is working properly, except that I have to refresh the page to update `$count`, So is there anyway to update the variable inside the label without manual refresh?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `Seen_messages.php` respond with the updated unread count, instead of always `1`, then use that response to update the user interface:

```
// ...
success: function(response) {
   if (isNaN(response)) {
       alert('Error!');
   } else {
       $('#num_msg').text(response);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the code above will show `0` on the counter if there's no unread messages. If you don't want this behavior, handle this case in the `else` block.

Answer (score 1):

How about writing a function to use with `setInterval()` to constantly check the server for new messages, and update the `<label>` count using jQuery. (BTW, your label is missing a closing tag!).

```
function get_msg_count(){
    $.ajax ({
        data: {}, // not really needed
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'get_msg_count.php', // page to return your msg count
        success: function(response) {
            // update the label with the count
            // response would be the number returned from PHP
            $('#num_msg').html(response); 
            }
        }); // End $.ajax
} // End Function

// and on DOM ready
$(function(){
    // check for new messages every 3 seconds(3000ms)
    setInterval(get_msg_count(), 3000) 
});
```

Then your Server Side script would return the message count, and you would just update the label which holds the count.